# process multiple form input fields

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter, form-processing

I have a `form` with `15` fields in it, and a `table` with same `15` fields names.

In a form only `4` fields are `mandatory` and remaining `11` are not `mandatory`..

now how i can process the form against database as I know i have `4` fields mandatory so i can easily process it against database..

but how i can process it when the form is coming to me with more then 4 fields to be processed againts database..

i don't want to use `if{} else{}` here to avoid `11*11` combination with the `4` mandatory fields

my main purpose here is i don't want to use `if else statement` here..

any suggestion or help would be great help... thanks in advance

Comment: You should show some code to illustrate your problem.

Comment: actually my requirement is only to know how i can process the form when the case is like i have stated.. in the question..

Comment: So you want somebody else to write the code for you?

Comment: no Sir i can write the code but i would like to know about the logic i can use here to avoid if else statement

Comment: To me, the question is not clear. "Check the 4 mandatory fields first. If they don't exist, error. If they exist, go through the other 11 and validate input. Construct your database call based on the available data."

Comment: To know "how to avoid if/else", show sample code using the if/else and ask how/if it could be optimized away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your query using string concatenation before executing it.

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO table_name SET required1 = 'value1', required2 = 'value2'; // etc

if (isset($optional_field)) $qry .= ", optional1 = 'optional_value1'";
```

Repeat the if statements as necessary for each field, then perform the actual query.

The alternative would be to insert all fields every time, making sure that optional fields the user did not fill out get set to their default values before inserting.

Comment: this is what i am looking for.. thank you very much sir..now i can implement my query based on your answer..thanks again..